# Compressible flow - subsonic and supersonic

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

Imagine a stream of isentropic gas flowing through a nozzle-diffuser. The gas that flows through the throat is subsonic. In this condition, the Mach number of the stream as it exits the broadcast side is less than 1. Is this statement false? Why?

Comment: I doesn't seem false to me.

Answer (score 0):

Mach number is defined as
$$M = \frac{u}{c}$$ where $c$ stands for the speed of sound in the local environment. If you assume the gas is subsonic then $u < c$ and so $M < 1$